# x11vnc, how to enable shift-key?

Tags: vnc

The shift key won't work through VNC to my Ubuntu server except for the characters ÅÄÖ. I'm using UTF-8 and sv_SE as locale. I find no options or settings that I can set nor do I find any information on google about people with similar problems.

Anyone here that might know what's wrong? 
`Connecting to Ubuntu 10.04 from Windows 7`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem seemed to be with `x11vnc`, the server that I run.

To enable the shift-keys I used the argument `-nomodtweak` when starting `x11vnc`.
This enabled the shift-keys for me!

Comment: Zolomon,
I am still having the issue.

I have x11vnc listed in the Startup Applications with this command line (found in my searches for starting x11vnc at startup ).

gnome-terminal -x x11vnc -nomodtweak -rfbauth /etc/x11vnc.pass -display :0 -forever -solid red

Any changes you can see that would help enable the shift key that I haven't included?  Perhaps the -xkb flag.

Thanks!

Comment: @Chronos: I have a swedish keyboard layout, that might be the cause of our differences?

Comment: +1 : Great! I was having the same problem... actually in my case only the () were working... the rest, as if it didn't have the shift key. My Keyb is Japanese, but the strange thing is that when I set the keyb layout to English-Latin (with a very different layout) most of the key worked correctly (even the shift key), but still was not perfect. Adding that option to x11vnc (and using Japanese layout) made my problems disappear. Thank you!

Comment: and even now in 2022 this fix solved it for me

Answer (score 3):

From reports on the web, it does appear that x11vnc has shift-related server-side problems, but various VNC clients DO also have their own similar client-side bugs.  I am on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS, using VNC to connect to a Windows 7 machine.  In my case, the shift key works normally when typing, but shift-click or ctrl-click with the mouse did not work at all!

Switching to gvncviewer (version 0.5.3-0ubuntu2) fixed the problem for me.  The shift-click bug still exists in xtightvncviewer (1.3.9-6.4ubuntu1) and xvnc4viewer (4.1.1+xorg4.3.0-37ubuntu5.0.2).

Some additional bug reports and discussions of the problem:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vnc4/+bug/275089
- http://sourceforge.net/p/virtualgl/mailman/message/19797016/